# excel calculate RMSE(root mean square error) got #VALUE error

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

- SQRT: Square root
- SUMSQ: Sum of squre
- COUNTA: count

My code:

```
=SQRT(SUMSQ(D2:D237-E2:E237)/COUNTA(D2:D237))
```

It looks correct but got #VALUE! error. I have set all cell to number format, is my code wrong ? how do I solve this ?

Comment: Have you entered it as an array formula, i.e. with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER?

Comment: @XOR LX Thank you, I don't know need `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` to calucute the value.

Comment: Post your data screenshot. It works for me.

Comment: what is the data you are using? the formula you posted works fine for me.

Comment: @Mithril In this case you do.